# $\int_0^{\pi/6}\frac{1-\cos2{(x/2)}}{2} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have worked up to this stage of the question :

$$\int_0^{\pi/6}\frac{1-\cos2{(x/2)}}{2} dx$$

So that's where I worked up to. Can someone please show me how to finish it off?

Comment: Does $\cos 2(x/2)$ mean something different from $\cos x$?

Comment: Yes I guess so.

Comment: Can you explain what the difference is, please?

Comment: Well I know that cos2 is a double angle while cos x is not

Comment: No I accidently type the question wrong and users answered it and, I was told to create a new thread.

Comment: It must have been $\cos^2 \dfrac x 2$, clearly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're making this more difficult than it needs to be:

$$\int_0^{\pi/6}\frac{1-\cos2{(x/2)}}{2} dx = \int_0^{\pi/6}\frac{1-\cos\Big(2(x/2)\Big)}{2} dx = \int_0^{\pi/6}\frac{1-\cos x}{2} dx$$

$$ = \frac 12\int_0^{\pi/6} \,dx \quad - \quad\frac 12 \int_0^{\pi/6} \cos x \,dx$$

Comment: OMG thankyou so much amWHY. Im sorry for the confusion before.

Comment: Don't fret. We all get mixed up at times! ;-)

Comment: @RedQueen10101: Yes, it can be happen for every one. +1

Comment: @amWhy: Deserves another TU, although I am confused about how the OP was written. Very odd! +1